# 401 error when trying to list Compute Engine instances using REST API and api key

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to list all instances in a Compute Engine project using the REST API and a public api key for server applications. Tried both with and without authorization header, but keep getting response 401:

```
APIKEY="API KEY"
PROJECT="PROJECT ID"

curl https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$PROJECT/aggregated/instances?key=$APIKEY

curl -H "Authorization: key=$APIKEY" https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$PROJECT/aggregated/instances?key=$APIKEY
```

I have allowed any IPs to connect when creating the api key . What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API ke](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys)y can be used only when the API that you are using is not requiring access to private user data. In the Google Documentation for the [instances:list API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list#auth) you're trying to use, you can read in link '[read more about authentication and authorization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization)' where you can find that requests made to Google Compute Engine must use OAuth 2.0 to authorized request. This is the reason when trying to curl this link, you get an error saying '401 Login Required'.
So, you need to create the [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) flow to authenticate first.